# TKinter Widget creation... Issue with arrangement of widgets

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I was trying to create some nested widgets within file widget however exit is appearing above open. I tried changing the index but still the problems persists any idea how to fix this?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import sys

class GuiBaseClass():
  def __init__(self,root):
      # create widgets

      self.root=root
      root.title('GUIBASECLASS V0.1')
      root.option_add('*tearOff', False)
      self.menu=dict()
      self.menubar = tk.Menu(root)         
      #File
      menu_file = tk.Menu(self.menubar)
      self.menubar.add_cascade(menu=menu_file,label='File',underline=0)
      menu_file.add_separator()
      menu_file.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.Exit,underline=0)
      #Edit
      menu_edit = tk.Menu(self.menubar)
      self.menubar.add_cascade(menu=menu_edit,label='Edit',underline=0)
      #Help
      menu_help = tk.Menu(self.menubar)
      menu_help.add_command(label='About', command=self.About, underline=0)
      self.menubar.add_cascade(menu=menu_help,label ='Help',underline=0)
      
      #config
      root.config(menu=self.menubar)
      self.menu['menubar'] = self.menubar
      self.menu['File']    = menu_file
      self.menu['Edit']    = menu_edit
      self.menu['Help']    = menu_help
      self.frame = ttk.Frame(root)
      self.frame.pack(fill='both',expand=True)

  # public functions
  def mainLoop(self):
      self.root.mainloop()
  def getFrame(self):
      return(self.frame)  
  def getMenu(self,entry):
      if entry in self.menu:
        return (self.menu[entry])
      else:
        # we create a new one
        last = self.menu['menubar'].index('end')   
        self.menu[entry]= tk.Menu(self.menubar)
        self.menu['menubar'].insert_cascade(
          last, menu=self.menu[entry],label=entry)
        return(self.menu[entry])
  # private functions
  def Exit(self,ask=True):
      res = tk.messagebox.askyesno(title='Are you sure',message='Really quit the application')
      if res:
        sys.exit(0)
      pass

  def About(self):
    print('print GUIBASECLASS V0.1')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root=tk.Tk()
    bapp = GuiBaseClass(root) 
    # example for using the BaseClass in other applications
    mnu=bapp.getMenu('Edit')
    mnu.add_command(label='Copy',command=lambda: print('Copy'))    
    # example for using getFrame
    frm=bapp.getFrame()
    btn=ttk.Button(frm,text="Button X",command=lambda: sys.exit(0))
    btn.pack()  
    bapp.mainLoop()


#!/usr/bin/python3

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
from GuiBaseClass import GuiBaseClass
import os , sys

class PumlEditor(GuiBaseClass):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)

        # Create the File menu and add a "Open..." option
        mnu_file = self.getMenu('File')
        mnu_file.add_command(0, label='Open...', underline=0, command=self.fileOpen)

        mnu_file.add_separator()

        # Create the main text area
        frame = self.getFrame()
        #insert tk.Text
        self.text = tk.Text(frame, wrap='word', undo=True)
        self.text.insert('end', 'Hello start writing, please...')
        self.text.delete('1.0','end')
        self.text.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

    def fileOpen(self, filename=''):
        # Open a file dialog to select a file to open
        if filename == "":
            filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()

        if filename != "":
            self.text.delete('1.0','end')
            file = open(filename,'r')
            for line in file:
                self.text.insert('end',line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("300x200")
    pedit = PumlEditor(root)
    # Create the PumlEditor instance and start the main loop
    root.title("PumlEditor 2022")
    if len(sys.argv)>1:
        if os.path.exits(sys.arg[1]):
            pedit.fileOpen(sys.argv[1])
    pedit.mainLoop()
```

Open to appear before exit in files widget

Comment: Please don't add filler characters to your question.

Comment: Ine tk.Tk() could write entire script. U have too many duplicates